# How to pass (access) ID inside rules method in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model-binding

I'm populating my form with user's data using form model binding.

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user_update', $user->id]]) !!}
```

Works perfectly. When I hit "Submit" I enter my UpdateUserRequest where I validate my input against some rules. In this case I want to keep unique e-mail address but of course we need to "skip uniqueness" for "this" row.

I have a rule

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,' . 123456,
```

and it works good as well when I will temporarily hardcode this ID (primary key from users table).

How to access this ID inside rules method? (Especially when I pass $user_id from controller).

1. Yes, Auth::user()->id works but obviously just for me. I deal also with profiles of other users.
2. I could pass this user's ID as input hidden and the access this from request / input but I don't find this as a good solution, am I right?
3. The same with url segment. I could grab this from url probably but maybe there is better way?

I'm inside rules() method and I'm dd() bunch of things but nothing works so far as I expect.

Thanks for any hints! :)

Comment: i don't understand what you're trying to achieve: do you want to skip "uniqueness" when updating a user's profile?

Comment: @DamienPirsy, exactly. 
Imagine that I'm updating someone's profile as superadmin. For example I'm changing John Doe's username but I'm leaving his e-mail as it is. Then I submit everything and Laravel performs validation. Laravel grabs input e-mail and compares it with existing e-mails in the database which makes no sense in this case because I didn't want to touch this field.

If I leave "required|unique" but I will remove "users,email,THIS_USERS_ID" I'll never be able to submit the form from obvious reasons. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Since the user ID is passed as part of the route url it makes sense to use that. That's why it's being passed along in the first place, because you need it to identify the exact entry you are working with (be it for updating, validating or whatever use you can find for it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the solution was very very easy.

```
$this->user->id
```

Full rule below:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,' . $this->user->id,
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve route parameters by their name with `route()->parameter()`:

```
$userId = $this->route()->parameter('userId'); // or whatever the name of the parameter is
```

Or a shortcut:

```
$userId = $this->route('userId');
```